# To find "row wise" "Mode" of a given data in R

Tags: r

Unlike `rowMeans()` and `rowMedians()`, which give us the calculated figure, `mode(x)` gives the storage mode of the data.

My Question - For the following data frame, how can I calculate `row wise` Mode?

Data:

```
    Item       A    B   C
    Book001    56   32  56
    Book002    95   95  20
    Book003    50   89  50
    Book004    6    65  40
```

I am reading my worksheet like this:

```
wk= loadWorkbook (".....xls")
df = readWorksheet (wk, Sheet="Sheet1", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : I have referred that page already! I am looking forward to finding Row wise mode when reading the input as data Frames from Excel.

Comment: The answer given by @dimitris_ps is correct and is also very slim and efficient.

Comment: @dimitris_ps 's answer is actually better than that given in the duplicate.  I hope it will be marked correct so other developers can use this as a reference.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, right, but the other is `base R` so they can "cohabit" ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
install.packages("modeest")
library(modeest)

apply(df[ ,2:length(df)], 1, mfv)
```

Comment: Very nice.  I never heard of this package before.

Comment: If you are looking for a "Base R" solution, then have a look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/standard-library-function-in-r-for-finding-the-mode) which answers a similar question.

Comment: @dimitris_ps : However, this doesn't work incase my data doesn't have a "frequently occurring term" . How can i solve such a case?